# Why do other open containers automatically close when using docker to log in to the container?

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, containers

The thing is, when I try to use vscode to connect to the remote server and use the container in docker, when I log in, the container that has been opened by other users will be automatically closed, and vscode will prompt “Successfully stopped non related container:nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.0."This matter is very troublesome to me. Could you please tell me how to solve it?

When I tried to attach the container to vscode, I followed the prompts of vscode (it should be about the setting of automatic opening of the container). How can I restore the opening of the container without automatically closing the containers of other users?

Comment: What commands exactly are you running?  A container is a wrapper around a single process; how do you "log in to the container"?  Aside from VSCode being involved, is there a programming-related task here, or is this just a login or dotfile problem of some sort?